# Terrarium time controlled usb socket

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm trying to write a script that controls my usb socket for my terrarium. I want it to turn on the lights at 22 and turn them off at 13.

```
light_on=22
light_off=13
# hour: time now
hour=$(date +%H)
if [ $hour -ge $light_on ] && [ $hour -lt $light_off ]
then
....
```

But everything I tried didn't work. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: There is no number that is both greater than 22 and also less than 13. What are you thinking should go where you have `....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is incorrect.

There is no number matching `n >= 22 && n < 13`. Your condition therefore never gets triggered. Use this instead:

```
light_on=22
light_off=13
hour=$(date +%H)

if (( hour < light_off || hour >= light_on )); then
    #on
else
    #off
fi
```

Also, `(( expr ))` is preferred for arithmetic expressions.

Comment: I will check this out.